# Time series - detecting seasonality to set frequency

Tags: r, time-series, frequency, forecast

I have daily level data for time series, and i am trying to understand whether it has a trend or seasonal component. The data i have is only for **699 days**, so less than 2 years. To convert it to time series what frequency should be set? I have read about it and suggested value is **7**, but looking at the data i feel there isn't a seasonal component in it at all. Below is the plot of the time series. 
[image: Time series plot]

Please suggest how can i go about it. Thanks!

Comment: Relevant - [How to identify the best frequency in a time series?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49173818/how-to-identify-the-best-frequency-in-a-time-series)

Comment: Daily 699 points is less than a year??

Comment: @42- sorry, i edited the question less than 2 years. So if i decompose it, it says there are less than 2 cycles.

Comment: So maybe you don’t have enough data.

Comment: Yes, if i do not assign any value for frequency i suppose it takes it as annual and two years don't get completed. So should i assign frequency of 7?